# rails, acts_as_votable 2nd instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, rubygems

I have an instance of acts_as_votable working on my app. But, I am having trouble with regards to how I would set up a 2nd instance of acts_as_votable.

At a high level, I want to add a 'Bookmark this post' vote in addition to my already existing "I like this post".

Can someone walk me through logically how I would do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually both of them are the same. A user `likes` a post and a user `bookmarks` a post both increase like and bookmark counters by +1 for that user.

You can use it like the following (using scopes):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_voter
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :user
end

# To like, bookmark a post by a user
@user.likes @post, vote_scope: 'like'
@user.likes @post, vote_scope: 'bookmark'

# Check if a user has liked or bookmarked a post
@user.voted_for? @post, vote_scope: 'like'
@user.voted_for? @post, vote_scope: 'bookmark'

# See a list of user likes and bookmarks
@user.find_voted_items(vote_scope: 'like')
@user.find_voted_items(vote_scope: 'bookmark')
```

That should do it. https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable has comprehensive examples.

Comment: Amaazzzinggg! Thanks!